# For loop over all columns in a pandas DataFrame except one (or two) in Python for scaling

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, transformation

I am transforming my data frame to perform PCA and fit it into an unsupervised KMeans clustering algorithm. I wish to preserve my target/classification column of ones and zeros unaffected. I really, don't want to perform the operation for each columns separately, therefore I want to use a for loop. Also, I want to keep having a data frame and NOT an array. This is what I've got so far:

```
# trim the outliers
for c in df:
    df[c] = df[df[c] < df[c].quantile(0.95)] # Remove top 5% of the values

# drop NaN 
df.dropna(inplace=True) 
df

# log transform each column while adding one to avoid -inf values
for c in df:
    df[c] = np.log10(df[c].values +1)
```

Imagine the column I don't want to transform is called df['class'] and I don't want to drop it out since if I remove NaN values during transformation I cannot merge back the values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Creating a list that has the columns you want to make changes on.
Applying any transform you want using `.apply()` and `lambda`.
The other columns will be the same.
So the code should be:

```py
cols = df.columns.difference(['class'])  # Getting all columns except the ones in []

# Applying The log10 on each column while adding 1 for just the columns in "cols"
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda col: np.log10(col+1), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I solved this by not using for loops and instead used .iloc. And also saved my column before dropping NaN.

```
class_column = df_num['class'] # save the column class so it doesn't get transformed
df_trim = df_num.iloc[:, 1:12][df_num.iloc[:, 1:12] < df_num.iloc[:, 1:12].quantile(0.95)] # remove top 5% outliers or more if you want


# log transform all values and add one to avoid -inf values
for c in df_trim:
    df_trim[c]= np.log10(df_trim[c].values +1)
    
# recover class_column
df_trim['class'] = class_column

# drop NaN
features = df_trim.dropna()
features.head()
```